# What is a "thick nose?"

Tags: meaning

The following is from Francois, Duc, de la Rochefoucauld's Portrait of Himself:

> I find it difficult to describe my nose; for it is neither snub, aquiline, thick, nor pointed, at least to the best of my belief; all I can say is that it is big rather than small, and somewhat too long.

I understand what is a snub nose, aquiline nose, and pointed nose, but I don't know what is a **thick nose**. May I ask what it is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a very common way of describing a nose, so I can see why one might find this confusing.

As @Liron has mentioned, **thick** means *"having a large distance between two sides"*.

With a nose, you may ask, well which sides? Is it at the bridge of the nose? At the nostril?

I would take it to mean thick all way the down. This is different to big since big suggests it's long, thick and sticks out quite a lot!

Other ways to consider the adjective in this context might be "broad" or "wide". It's fairly arbitrary and open to your interpretation though.

Comment: “Thick” can also mean “heavily built”. For example, a manual laborer might have “thick hands” with tough calloused skin and stubby fingers. There’s a connotation of coarseness or the opposite of elegance.

Comment: Agreed @ColleenV